# To denote the transpose, should I use $o^{[1]T}$ or ${o^{[1]}}^T$?

Tags: notation

I have a 2-layer neural network model shown below.

[image]

I'm using $o^{[1]}$ to denote the output of the first layer and $o^{[2]}$ for the 2nd layer.

During the computation, I need to transpose $o^{[1]}$.

To denote the transpose, should I use $o^{[1]T}$ or ${o^{[1]}}^T$?

Comment: Probably $(o^{[1]})^T$ is most clear

Comment: I agree with Slugger, $(o^{[1]})^T$ is clear. Both of the variants suggested in the question seem confusing to me. You might also consider changing the notation altogether, e.g. to $o_{[1]}$ and transpose $o_{[1]}^T$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you absolutely must choose between those two options, then ${o^{[1]}}^T$ is better since it doesn't seem to associate the $[1]$ and the $T$.

If it's an option, I'd advise at least considering using $(o^{[1]})^T$. (it somewhat depends on how heavily you're already using parentheses/braces)